# Angular Currency Pipe to include if zero is present in end after decimal

Tags: html, angular, angular-pipe

I am using Angular. 
It is strict that I need to show full Number that I get from backend

I know Zero at the last example " `123.450` is same as `123.45` but according to the client we need to show full number.

```
 <td>{{ material.customerPrice | currency:'EUR':true}}</td>

Component: 
this.material.customerPrice = "234.54530" // Output should be : 234.54530 not 234.5453
or
this.material.customerPrice = "12.5456540" // Output should be : 12.5456540 not 12.545654
```

there is no fixed digit after the decimal.

Is there any other parameter that I need to add in the angular currency pipe that I can show full digit.

Answer (score 2):

The first 3 arguments to [the angular currency pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) work like this:

`currency:<Currency Code>:<Symbol display mode>:<min digits before the decimal>.<min digits after decimal>-<max digits after decimal>`

So for your case, you want at least 1 digit before the decimal, at least 2 digits after, and at most 20 digits after the decimal (replace 20 with whatever your max is)

EDIT: Since you always want to preserve the last zero, you will have to add it to your template manually, as the currency pipe cannot do this on its own. Something like this:

```
 <td>
   {{ material.customerPrice | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'1.2-20' }}
   <ng-container *ngIf="material.customerPrice.toString().split('').pop() === '0'">0</ng-container>
</td>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work.. max number will be 20, but `234.54530`  result is still `234.5453`

Comment: I see, what you are requesting is not fully possible with the angular currency pipe. There is no option to pad with 0, I would suggest seeing if the number toString ends in a 0, and if it does, append that to the output in the template. I have edited my answer with a simple example above that may have to be adjusted for your specific logic

Comment: In my case it worked with a modification because of my use case. I needed to show a currency with 2 decimal points, I received: 905.5023123 and need to show: 905.50, and with '1.2-2' it worked. Thanks!